# How to embed a file in an objective-c project and extract it in running time?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a code written in objective-c for OS X. I want to create a text file right after the user runs the program and save it under the Documents folder.

Right now I stored all the text in a String variable and on run time I write it in a file. But the problem is that I don't want to have hardcode all the content of the text file in my code.

Is there any way to embed the text file in the project and when the user runs the application extract it and store it under a certain path?

P.s. I am using XCode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the file to the project. 
In Build Phases add a new Copy Files build phase and choose Resources folder.

In your code use NSBundle

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But would you please explain it with more details? I know how to add a file to the project (right click on project and add new file!) But I don't have any idea about NSBundle and other things you said.

Comment: Actually in XCode 6 I can't see Build Phases!

Comment: Click on the Xcode project file proxy. Looks like an Xcode file. The click on the target in the late sidebar of the center content area. Then click on Build Phases atop the center content area. Xcode help has info on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my version of XCode (11.5), any text file that I add to my project automatically gets copied to the resources folder in my application bundle. (I don't need to do anything special to get the file into the application bundle.)

Then, to read it at runtime:

```
NSString* licensePath = [NSBundle.mainBundle.resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"License.txt"];
NSString* license = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:licensePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```